# Find the smallest float in a file and printing the line

Tags: python, floating-point, min

I have a data file like this:

```
1 13.4545
2 10.5578
3 12.5578
4 5.224
```

I am trying to find the line with the smallest float number and print or write the entire line (including the integer) to another file. so i get this:

```
4 5.224
```

I have this but does not work:

```
with open(file) as f:
    small = map(float, line)
    mini = min(small)
    print mini
```

also tried using this:

```
with open(file) as f:
    mylist = [[line.strip(),next(f).strip()] for line in f]
    minimum = min(mylist, key = lambda x: float(x[1]))
    print minimum
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your data file, we can iterate over each line of the file inside `min` since `min` takes an iterator:

```
>>> with open(fn) as f:
...    print min(f)
... 
1 13.4545
```

Obviously, that is using the ascii value of the integer for determining min.

Python's [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) takes a key function:

```
def kf(s):
    return float(s.split()[1])

with open(fn) as f:
    print min(f, key=kf)
```

Or:

```
>>> with open(fn) as f:
...    print min(f, key=lambda line: float(line.split()[1]))
... 
4 5.224
```

The advantage (in both versions) is that the file is processed line by line -- no need to read the entire file into memory.

The entire line is printed but only the float part is used to determine the min value of that line.

---

To fix YOUR version, the issue is your first list comprehension. Your version has `next()` in it which you probably thought was the next number. It isn't: It is the next line:

```
>>> with open(fn) as f:
...      mylist = [[line.strip(),next(f).strip()] for line in f]
... 
>>> mylist
[['1 13.4545', '2 10.5578'], ['3 12.5578', '4 5.224']]
```

The first list comprehension should be:

```
>>> with open(fn) as f:
...    mylist=[line.split() for line in f]
... 
>>> mylist
[['1', '13.4545'], ['2', '10.5578'], ['3', '12.5578'], ['4', '5.224']]
```

Then the rest will work OK (but you will have the split list in this case -- not the line -- to print):

```
>>> minimum=min(mylist, key = lambda x: float(x[1]))
>>> minimum
['4', '5.224']
```

Comment: Yo Dawg! (Remeber me?). Why not make it a single line? `with open(fn) as f: print min(f, key=lambda s: float(s.split()[1]))` This would be even more compact ;) ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao Because python is not perl and because stackoverflow is not code-golf.  Answers shouldbe readable

Comment: @TerryJanReedy lol bro, you did not get the ult mot of the comment. dawg's answers are always of the top quality and need no changes ever!! I just commented that coz it would be a single line. Anyway, thanks for telling me that Perl is bad! I would think twice now before even thinking of learning Perl. Thanks again, good day!

Comment: thank you, very simple solutions! I used your 3rd version, worked great!

Answer (score 2):

You were quite near, this is the minimal edit needed

```
with open(fl) as f:                             # don't use file as variable name
    line = [i.strip().split() for i in f]       # Get the lines as separate line no and value
    line = [(x[0],float(x[1])) for x in line]   # Convert the second value in the file to float
    m = min(line,key =  lambda x:x[1])          # find the minimum float value, that is the minimum second argument.
    print "{} {}".format(m[0],m[1])             # print it. Hip Hip Hurray \o/
```

Comment: @JohnY (*Secretly speaking*) I always use that. This is because, the OP will not feel let down that he was completely wrong. On a lighter vein, *Hey! Johny, The OP has written with open(file) as f:* :)

Comment: Can you please explain your downvote? I would like to learn and improve my answer, Your valuable feedback will help me a lot. Please do reply as to what is the flaw in my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @octain You are welcome bro. Enjoy your life as a coder! All the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a=open('d.txt','r')

d=a.readlines()
m=float(d[0].split()[1])

for x in d[1:]:
    if float(x.split()[1])<m:
        m=float(x.split()[1])

print m
```

Comment: This does not print the line with the minimum

Comment: It also does not explain how and why this is different from the original.

Answer (score 0):

**map:**

map(function, iterable, ...)
    Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results. [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Demo:

```
>>> map(float , ["1.9", "2.0", "3"])
[1.9, 2.0, 3.0]

>>> map(float , "1.9")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .
>>>
```

---

1. Read input file by csv module because structure of input file is fixed.
2. Set `small` and `small_row` variables to None.
3. Read file row by row.
4. Type Casting of second item from the row, from string to float.
5. Check small variable is None or less then second item of row.
6. If yes the assign small value and small_row respectivly

Demo:

```
import csv

file1 = "1_d.txt"

small = None
small_row = None
with open(file1) as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ')
    for row in root:
        item = float(row[1])
        if small==None or small>item:
            small = item
            small_row = row

print "small_row:", small_row
```

Output:

```
$ python 3.py 
small_row: ['4', '5.224']
```